# How to get the home address of a given actor system

Tags: java, akka

When I start an akka system with remoting enabled I get the following lines in the logs

```
Starting remoting
....
Remoting now listens on address: [akka.tcp://myactorsystemname@127.0.0.1:4000]
```

From within my actor I want to print out `akka.tcp://myactorsystemname@127.0.0.1:4000`. I have an instance of the ActorSystem object with me but I cannot work out how to get this string. Can someone provide me a Java API to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java you can get the `akka.actor.Address` object as follows and its string representation is your requested string.

```
Address addr = system.provider().getDefaultAddress();
```